# Swagger UI (SpringFox) with JAX-RS in Spring Boot application - Failed to load API definition

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, swagger-ui, springfox

I followed this guide in order to enable Swagger UI with JAX-RS in Spring Boot Application: https://atechref.com/using-swagger-2-with-spring-boot-spring-fox-and-jax-rs-project/ but I get the following error all the time: Failed to load API definition

[image]

I use following dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring boot version: 2.3.3.RELEASE

These are the classes I have right now:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({MyAppWebSpringConfig.class})
public class MyAppApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@Component
@Primary
public class CombinedResourceProvider implements SwaggerResourcesProvider{

  @Resource
  private InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider;

  public List<SwaggerResource> get() {

    SwaggerResource jerseySwaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
    jerseySwaggerResource.setLocation("/my-app/swagger.json");
    jerseySwaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
    jerseySwaggerResource.setName("Jersey");

    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(jerseySwaggerResource),
        inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider.get().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

}

@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/my-app")
public class MyAppResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig{

  @Autowired
  public MyAppResourceConfig(@Qualifier("ets-feature") Feature jerseyOperationalFeature){
    register(jerseyOperationalFeature);
    register(MyAppResource.class);

    //exceptions
    register(GenericExceptionMapper.class);

    configureJersey();
  }

  public void configureJersey(){
    BeanConfig swaggerConfig = new BeanConfig();
    swaggerConfig.setBasePath("/my-app");
    SwaggerConfigLocator.getInstance().putConfig(SwaggerContextService.CONFIG_ID_DEFAULT, swaggerConfig);

    packages(getClass().getPackage().getName(), ApiListingResource.class.getPackage().getName());


  }



@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.my.app"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@Import({CoreSpringConfig.class})
public class MyAppWebSpringConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

  @Bean
  public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.my.app"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build();
  }

}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?..

Comment: I have the same issue. Will be happy to know if you found a resolution!